# Invalid Cast Exception with FreshEssentials BindablePicker

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have used FreshEssentials BindablePicker in other projects fine, but am having a very strange problem with a particular Page/PageModel.

I have stripped the Page and PageModel right down to the following:
Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage x:Class="Manager.Pages.Config.RemoteConnectionsPage"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:fe="clr-namespace:FreshEssentials;assembly=FreshEssentials">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Main Page" />
            <fe:BindablePicker DisplayProperty="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Environments}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

PageModel:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using FreshMvvm;
using PropertyChanged;

namespace Manager.PageModels.Config
{
    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class RemoteConnectionsPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
    {
        public enum Environment
        {
            Live,
            Test,
            Third
        }

        public class EnvironmentPickerItem
        {
            public string Name {
                get {
                    return Env.ToString ();
                }
            }

            public Environment Env {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
        public RemoteConnectionsPageModel ()
        {
            List<EnvironmentPickerItem> _Environments;
            _Environments = new List<EnvironmentPickerItem> ();
            _Environments.Add (new EnvironmentPickerItem () { Env = Environment.Live });
            _Environments.Add (new EnvironmentPickerItem () { Env = Environment.Test });
            _Environments.Add (new EnvironmentPickerItem () { Env = Environment.Third });
            this.Environments = _Environments;
        }

        public List<EnvironmentPickerItem> Environments {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I run the application, I get the exception below (full stack trace truncated):

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
>     at FreshEssentials.Droid.BindablePickerRendererDroid.OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs`1[TElement] e) [0x00031] in C:\Users\Michael\Documents\FreshEssentials\src\Droid\Renderers\BindablePickerRendererDroid.cs:46
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].SetElement (TElement element) [0x000f4] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:190
>     at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element) [0x00027] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\VisualElementRenderer.cs:131

Looking at the source for the BindablePickerRendererDroid from the FreshEssentials repository, it appears to be the line:

```
((ObservableCollection<string>)e.NewElement.Items).CollectionChanged += RowsCollectionChanged;
```

in this method.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BindablePicker> e)
        {
            if (e.OldElement != null)
                ((ObservableCollection<string>)e.OldElement.Items).CollectionChanged -= RowsCollectionChanged;

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                ((ObservableCollection<string>)e.NewElement.Items).CollectionChanged += RowsCollectionChanged;
                if (Control == null)
                {
                    var button = new AButton(Context) { Focusable = false, Clickable = true, Tag = this, Text = e.NewElement.Title };
                    button.SetOnClickListener(PickerListener.Instance);
                    SetNativeControl(button);
                }
                UpdatePicker();
            }

            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }
```

The strange thing is that taking the above exact code into a brand new project works fine. I have checked versions of FreshEssentials and FreshMVVM, and they're identical between the working and non-working projects.

Anyone come across this, and/or any thoughts?

Full Xamarin Studio and other version info below:

> === Xamarin Studio Community ===
>
> Version 6.1.4 (build 1)
>   Installation UUID: 462e6ba8-9cb7-4b87-acc8-9dfb0ab2c6f7
>   Runtime:
>     Mono 4.6.2 (mono-4.6.0-branch/ac9e222) (64-bit)
>     GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
>
> Package version: 406020016
>
> === NuGet ===
>
> Version: 3.4.3.0
>
> === Xamarin.Profiler ===
>
> Version: 0.33.2
>   Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler
>
> === Xamarin.Android ===
>
> Version: 7.0.2.42 (Xamarin Studio Community)
>   Android SDK: /Users/jameslavery/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
>     Supported Android versions:
>         2.3   (API level 10)
>         4.0.3 (API level 15)
>         4.1   (API level 16)
>         4.3   (API level 18)
>         4.4   (API level 19)
>         5.0   (API level 21)
>         5.1   (API level 22)
>         6.0   (API level 23)
>
> SDK Tools Version: 24.4.1
>   SDK Platform Tools Version: 23.1
>   SDK Build Tools Version: 23.0.1
>
> Java SDK: /usr
>   java version "1.7.0_71"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
>
> Android Designer EPL code available here:
>   https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL
>
> === Xamarin Android Player ===
>
> Version: 0.6.5
>   Location: /Applications/Xamarin Android Player.app
>
> === Apple Developer Tools ===
>
> Xcode 8.0 (11246)
>   Build 8A218a
>
> === Xamarin.iOS ===
>
> Version: 10.3.1.8 (Xamarin Studio Community)
>   Hash: 7beaef4
>   Branch: cycle8-xi
>   Build date: 2016-12-20 02:58:14-0500
>
> === Xamarin.Mac ===
>
> Version: 2.10.0.120 (Xamarin Studio Community)
>
> === Build Information ===
>
> Release ID: 601040001
>   Git revision: e606823f2dd01b4552216c013b597a73bec2068f
>   Build date: 2017-01-10 17:28:57-05
>   Xamarin addins: c92d0626d347aaa02839689eaac2961d24c9f446
>   Build lane: monodevelop-lion-cycle8
>
> === Operating System ===
>
> Mac OS X 10.11.6
>   Darwin Jamess-MacBook-Pro.local 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0
>       Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016
>       root:xnu-3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
>
> === Enabled user installed addins ===
>
> StyleCop Support 1.0.1.9
>   Gorilla Player 0.9.1.2
>   XamlStyler 1.0.2

Comment: Looking at the line you post from the FreshEssentials source it looks like it expects an collection of `strings`? While you are binding a collection of `Environment`

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Yes I agree, except the line I posted is deep within the renderer, and internally it creates a collection of strings (I assume), using the _DisplayName_ property.

The interesting point is that this works fine in a brand new project, with the _same code_!